# Linux commands to substitute pattern with conditions

Tags: linux, shell

I am still learning Linux commands, and I was wondering if anyone could help me out with what I am trying to do: I have a file like this:

```
3       rs123     0       600001   A       G
3       rs345     0        600002  T       G
3   3:124369637:A_G 0   124369637   A   G
3   3:124369637:G_GT    0   124369637   G   GT
```

And I am trying to substitute anything after the second occurrence of the colon with "ID" only if the length of the 5th and 6th columns are greater than 1, while if the length is 1 I need to remove whatever is after the second occurrence of the colon. So I would like this:

```
3       rs123     0       600001   A       G
3       rs345     0        600002  T       G
3   3:124369637 0   124369637   A   G
3   3:124369637:ID  0   124369637   G   GT
```

I have tried in several ways, and I can get up to some point but I am stuck with the last part. Also, what I have now seems long and contorted. Any advice is very much appreciated! Thank you!

First I do this to add ":ID" to all the cases with this format 3:124369637:

```
awk -F' ' '//{gsub(/[:][A-Za-z].*/, ":ID", $2); print} file.txt
```

Then I tried this to keep the ID only for cases where the length of columns 5 and 6 are >1 (But this doesn't work):

```
awk -F' ' '{
if (length($5) ==1 && length($6) ==1 && $2 ~/ID/ )
    gsub(/ID/,"");print;
    else
    print;
    }' file.txt
```

Comment: The 5th column is greater than 1? but it is a letter

Comment: Hi, yes the length of the 5th column is greater than 1 (i.e. AG instead of just A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
{
    if (length($5) == 1 && length($6) == 1 )
    {
        sub(/:[^:]*$/, "", $2)
        print
    }
    else if ( length($5) >= 1 && length($6) >= 1 )
    {
        sub(/:[^:]*$/, ":ID", $2)
        print
    }
    else
        print
}'
file.txt
```

Try this. You may want to modify the replacement logit, I suppose that every line has at least two colons.

Comment: Dear zhujs, this is exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks so much!! I now see my lack of knowledge of if/else statement... thanks for your help!